# Django Foreign Key Lookup in QuerySet

Tags: django

I am writing an app for a sports league. I have models for Teams and the Schedule. When a user selects a Team, they can see that team's wins, losses, ties. I'd like to show all the games from that team.

Models.py

```
class Teams(models.Model):
    team = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=225, blank=True, null=True)
    sport_id = models.ForeignKey(Sports, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    division = models.CharField(max_length=225, blank=True, null=True)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    win = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    loss = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    tie = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'teams'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.team_name

class Schedule(models.Model):
    match = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    match_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    home = models.ForeignKey(Teams, related_name='home_set',  blank=True, null=True)
    away = models.ForeignKey(Teams, related_name='away_set', blank=True, null=True)
    home_score = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    away_score = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'schedule'
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s at %s' % (self.away, self.home)
```

And my relevant views:

```
class TeamView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = "teamsports/teamview.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TeamView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        q = self.request.GET.get('team_name')
        context['team'] = Teams.objects.get(team=q)
        context['game_list']=Schedule.objects.filter(home=q).values() | Schedule.objects.filter(away=q).values()
        return context
```

The Template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Team Name: {{ team }}</h1>
    <h1>Wins: {{ team.win }}</h1>
    <h1>Losses: {{ team.loss }}</h1>

    <h1>Results: </h1>
        <h1>{% for game_list in game_list|dictsort:"match_date" %}</h1>
            <p>Date: {{game_list.match_date|date }} Home Team:  {{ game_list.home_team }}  Score: {{ game_list.home_score }} Away Team: {{ game_list.away_team }} Score {{ game_list.away_score|linebreaksbr }}</p>
            {% endfor %}

    <li><a href="/standings/">Pick another, ya jabroni</a></li>

{% endblock %}
```

This works! But the teams in 'game_list' appear as their id numbers, not names. How do I look back into my team model to get the team name?
Things I've tried:

1. Writing a large query with home and away games using .values(team_name). Error on the query fields not matching up, which sort of makes sense to me.
2. Writing a separate view for upcoming games and using "include". Still having a problem matching the opposing team to the game.

Things I've considered:

1. Write a template tag
2. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062955/django-foreign-key-queries) or using Q

Any guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `values()` on all the querysets? That turns the data from Django model instances - with the ability to follow foreign keys - into dumb dictionaries.

Instead you should do a single query to get all your matches, sorting it in the query itself, and return that.

```
from django.db.models import Q
game_list = Schedule.objects.filter(Q(home=q) | Q(away=q)).order_by('match_date').select_related('home', 'away')
```

The `select_related` clause is not required, but makes following the FKs in the template more efficient.

Now your template can just be:

```
{% for game in game_list %}
   <p>Date: {{ game.match_date|date }} Home Team:  {{ game.home.team_name }}  Score: {{ game.home_score }} Away Team: {{ game.away.team_name }} Score {{ game.away_score }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. I'm still reading up on Q so I understand it better, but I'm receiving an error "'Q' object has no attribute 'order_by'".

Comment: Hmm, are you sure you have the parentheses in the right place? There are two close parens after the second Q.

Comment: OK - that was fixed. But now the rendered template isn't displaying any data. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I was using the wrong variable name inside the template loop; corrected now.

Comment: Works, thank you so much. Can I ask a follow up? The variable "game" isn't in any of my models. How does it work in the loop?

Comment: It's like any other for loop; when you do `for x in [1, 2, 3]` the variable `x` takes each value in turn.

Comment: I feel dumb. Thanks again